# Autofac says type is not registered, only happens on one environment

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

We have a Windows service, using Topshelf. With it we are checking if we get messages from a message queue, then send a mail. It works on my local machine, the internal test environment and the external test environment.
However, when I deploy it to the live environment, I see in our logging that we are getting an exception on resolving the ISmtpMailService.

I get the error below

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing a registered user 0280ceb3-373f-4a3b-95ca-95e0cc23009a:
Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 
'Mail.SMTP.Services.ISmtpMailService' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register
a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the 
ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency. at 
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at 
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at 
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context) at 
Web.Identity.QueueMonitor.MQ.QueueMonitor.<sendRegistrationConfirmationAsync>d__3.MoveNext() in 
D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\6d5b3b1d63a0a2d4\Web\Web.Identity.QueueMonitor\MQ\QueueMonitor.cs:line 94 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() at 
QueueMonitor.MQ.QueueMonitor.ReceivedHandler(Object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs e) in 
D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\6d5b3b1d63a0a2d4\Web\Web.Identity.QueueMonitor\MQ\QueueMonitor.cs:line 65
```

Then I have the method(s) where I register the Autofac container

```
        private static IContainer getContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // Register Services from the BLL our application needs to function.
            registerServices(builder);

            // Build and return the container.
            return builder.Build();
        }

        private static void registerServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {

            // Register default mailclients
            builder.RegisterType<SmtpClient>().As<ISmtpClient>().SingleInstance();

            // Register base mailservices
            builder.RegisterType<SmtpMailService>().As<ISmtpMailService>().SingleInstance();
        }
```

Finally I call a method when we get a message from the queue, this method tries to resolve the ISmtpMailService.

```
        private static async Task sendRegistrationConfirmationAsync(MessageUserRegistered userRegistered)
        {
            using (var scope = getContainer().BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var mailService = scope.Resolve<ISmtpMailService>();

                // Extracted, sending mail here
           }
        }
```

Does anyone have any idea why we get the error, but only on the live environment?

Comment: Have you tried to resolve ISmtpClient for example? Or change the from singleton to transient/scope? At least it would help to understand the problem

Comment: Is it the real code ? How is this application hosted ? how do you publish it ? Maybe the publish on live environment has a problem. Could you republish and delete everything before.